# DateTime ToString not formatting correctly with ddMMy specifier

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following format for my `DateTime.ToString`:

```
ddMMy
```

However this format returns a date with two digits for the year i.e. `16` instead of `6`. See the following code example:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2016, 9, 12);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("ddMMyy"));
```

This displays:

> 120916

Instead of the expected:

> 12096

To further complicate things the following code:

```
string date = "12096";
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddMMy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Produces the output:

> 20060912

Is there a format I can pass to get my required output of `13096` or is this a bug in the `DateTime.ToString` implementation?

Comment: Where do you get that is the "expected" output. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) states that `yy` will give an output of `The year, from 00 to 99.`!

Comment: This is **not** a bug. It works exactly as specified and documented :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the doubling of the format specifiers.

`y` does not output the last digit of the year only. It outputs `9` for `2009`, but `16` for `2016`, whereas `yy` outputs `09` for `2009` and `16` for `2016`. This is also true for other format specifies.

Examples: Consider July 1st 2005

```
dMy => 175
dMyy => 1705
dMMyy => 10705
ddMMyy => 010705
```

A general rule is: If you use a single letter, there will be no leading zeros. If you use two letters, there may be leading zeros. More letters provide additional options specific to the date part (for example, `yyyy` provides the full year, `MMM`provides the shortened month name).

To solve your problem, I'd combine date formatting with maths. You could try this:

```
string date = dt.ToString("ddMM") + (dt.Year % 10).ToString();
```

For your parsing issue: Because of what I said above you can conclude that parsing `12096` as `206-09-12` is entirely correct. If it was 20**16**, the previous formatting would have output `16`. The fact that your year-part in the string consists only of a `6` and you're not "forcing" leading zeros causes the algorithm to consider the single `6` as `2006`. Everything is fine so far.

This: Even if you use my above example for formatting 2016 as `6`, parsing will always produce `2006`instead of `2016`.

Short: If you want 2016, make sure to put the `16` in your string, not just `6`.

Comment: Misread? [The "y" custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_34): *The "y" custom format specifier represents the year as a one-digit or two-digit number. If the year has more than two digits, only the two low-order digits appear in the result. If the first digit of a two-digit year begins with a zero (for example, 2008), the number is formatted without a leading zero.* I think it's crystal clear :)